How long does it take for the body to "reset" after being exposed to the sun?
What is the time that it takes for the body to "reset" after being exposed to the sun?
Example:
I have fairly pale skin, and I usually burn after being in the sun for 45 minutes or more.  If I am in the sun for an hour, I will burn; but, if I am in the sun for only 30 minutes, I will be fine.
I can even be out in the sun for 30 minutes each day and not get burnt.  This means that, at a certain point, my body "resets" and the timer for being safely exposed to the sun without getting a sunburn restarts at zero.
It makes sense that it may take longer for the body to "reset" depend on the level of ambient sun that is still exposed to the body (e.g. partial shade, full shade, dark room, etc.).  A gradient or factor on the time to account for this may also be necessary to answer the question.
Based on my initial research, there seems to be no scholarly work on this topic (as evidenced by my "sources") and little consensus on what this "reset" time is.
Some sources say that there is no defined "reset" period (which I find hard to believe) ("...is not a scientifically recognized or established practice.") (https://www.quora.com/Sunscreen-How-long-do-you-need-to-be-in-the-shade-in-order-to-reset-your-sunburn-timer).
Other sources say that there is a 1:4 ratio between sun and "shade"; however, this is cited more as an "old wives' tale" than an actual answer and does not define what "shade" means (see my above comment on ambient sunlight).  I could not find the source of this information again.
Still other sources say that time on a magnitude of days ("...it can take two of three days...") is required to "reset" the skin (https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/1af2wna/after_spending_time_in_the_sun_how_much_time_in/); however, I have found this to be false based on my own observations and resistance to sunburns after no more than 24 hours.

Just to note, I'm finding little other than the odd Q&A site post - i.e. no listed research (Google Scholar et al.) for "sun exposure refractory period". The OP is not alone.

I think this is one of the things that seems like it should be simple to answer but almost certainly is not, with too many different factors that likely have a lot of individual variability. It's not as if "sunburn" involves a single pharmacokinetic process. And even though it seems like a question with practical utility, it's not really approaching the question from a direction that a medical scientist would be likely to approach.

you can't answer "how long does it take for the body to reset after being exposed to food?" (in other words, how long to be hungry again after eating) even though you can clearly bracket it the same way you can sun exposure. Ditto thirst after drinking, tiredness after sleeping, and tons of other things. The differences among the "exposures" and in each person's "recovery rate" - person to person and instance to instance - are too great. Half an hour every day for 10 days might add up to a burn, though not after 8 or 9 days. There is no reset, really.

When you say "my...resistance to sunburns after no more than 24 hours", you're referring to a relative resistance. The body doesn't "reset", it responds. In the case of sun exposure, melanocytes respond by increasing melanin production, which protects against sunburn (to a degree). There are also other (less obvious) immediate changes which confer some protection. These allow you to be exposed to sunlight for longer periods without burning. But nothing "resets" (which is why there are no sources for it).

@anongoodnurse The protective effect of melanin is actually pretty impressive if it's acquired over a long period of time. I learned this painful lesson as a boy. I grew up south of Miami, so I spent the first 12 years of my life outdoors never wearing a shirt or long pants if I didn't have to. I was pretty much immune to sunburn. Never once had one despite often being outside on the water for 12 hours at a time. Then when I was 13 I moved away for a year and then came back. Never having thought about sunburns before, I promptly learned what they were. 1st/2nd degree burns over almost 50% BSA.

@CareyGregory What a painful lesson, but so relatable! (Think: a northerner going to WaltDisney World in the winter, lol!) It used to be thought that it took hours for melanocytes to start producing melanin; it actually takes only minutes to begin. It really is impressive stuff.

@anongoodnurse Do you think it's possible that explains what OP has observed? For example, OP spends 30 minutes in the sun, which initiates melanin production, but it takes x number of hours for it to reach a protective level. Seems like a reasonable explanation and I'd be surprised if there's no research on this.

@CareyGregory - I think that's absolutely what happens (that plus an inflammatory response which does confer some protection for subsequent exposures), though most of the literature focuses on sunburn and skin damage, so it's buried in there somewhere. But there's no reset, in that there isn't any going back to baseline, not for a long time (like your year away), and depending on age (young better than elderly) and damage done, sometimes not at all.

These are exactly the sorts of processes I had in mind in my comment, but it's not even just melanin, there's also a host of DNA repair mechanisms that are regulated by sun exposure. And the activation is not linear and not even monotonic. And "time" is not particularly useful by itself because it's going to depend on light intensity too which is going to depend on latitude, season, weather, time of day... So, reset after what?

@BryanKrause - re: "reset" and "after what", Agreed. I'll assume after x unit of UVy exposure back to pre-exposure baseline, which may or may not ever occur. (Oh, and there's more than one kind of melanin (genetic component), is that what you mean by not monotonic?)

@anongoodnurse I was thinking specifically of p53 when mentioning not monotonic; activated at low to modest insults, but not strong.
